# XML of Django model and models related to it

Tags: python, xml, django, model

I have a model class Equip, that it's a subclass of User (i think it doesn't matter) and a Player model.

```
class Team(auth.models.User):
    emaile = models.EmailField('email',null=False,unique=True,)
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Equip)
```

In views i have:

```
class ConnegResponseMixin(TemplateResponseMixin):

def render_xml_object_response(self, objects, **kwargs):
    xml_data = serializers.serialize(u"xml", objects, **kwargs)
    return HttpResponse(xml_data, content_type=u"application/xml")

def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
    if 'extension' in self.kwargs:
        try:
            objects = [self.object]
        except AttributeError:
            objects = self.object_list
        return self.render_xml_object_response(objects=objects)
    else:
        return super(ConnegResponseMixin, self).render_to_response(context


class  teamDetail(DetailView, ConnegResponseMixin):
model = Equip
template_name = 'competition/team_detail.html'


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(teamDetail,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

How can I have a xml like:
   Team:
       Name:teamname
       email:teamemail
       players:{
           player:
                name:playername
           player2:
                name:player2name

I have tried to create a new class TeamXML

```
class TeamXML():
def __init__(self, equip):
    self.username = equip.username
    self.email = equip.correoe
    self.isTeamValid = equip.isTeamValid
    self.players = Jugador.objects.filter(team=equip)
```

and in the views I have changed the function render_xml_object_response to:

```
def render_xml_object_response(self, objects, **kwargs):
    if objects[0].__class__ == Team:
        objectA = TeamXML(objects[0])           
        xml_data = serializers.serialize(u"xml", objectA, **kwargs)
    else:
        xml_data = serializers.serialize(u"xml", objects, **kwargs)
    return HttpResponse(xml_data, content_type=u"application/xml")
```

But it returns to me the error: 'TeamXML' object is not iterable.
How can I do TeamXML iterable or how can I do to return a XML with team and players like attribute of team.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
116.         return self.render_to_response(context)
File "/home/eloi/Models/DjangoLoL/LoL/competition/views.py" in render_to_response
  59.             return self.render_xml_object_response(objects=objects)
File "/home/eloi/Models/DjangoLoL/LoL/competition/views.py" in render_xml_object_response
  48.           xml_data = serializers.serialize(u"xml", objectA, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py" in serialize
  128.     s.serialize(queryset, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py" in serialize
  52.         for obj in queryset:

Exception Type: TypeError at /team/10.xml
Exception Value: 'TeamXML' object is not iterable
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnally solved with dexml. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dexml/

With this:
Models.py

```
class PlayerXML(dexml.Model):
    name = fields.String()
    rol = fields.String()
    email = fields.String()

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.name = player.name
        self.rol = player.rol
        self.email = player.email

class TeamXML(dexml.Model):
    username = fields.String()
    email = fields.String()
    players = fields.List(Jugador)

    def __init__(self, team):
        self.username = team.username
        self.email = team.correoe
        for item in Jugador.objects.filter(team=team):
            self.players.append(PlayerXML(item))
```

And Views.py:

```
team_xml = TeamXML(objects[0])
team_xml = TeamXML(objects[0])
xml_data = team_xml.render()xml_data = team_xml.render()
return HttpResponse(xml_data, content_type=u"application/xml")
```

Thanks for the help :)